# How to change the website searchbar-name?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a website and the website have this name in the searchbar:

> websitename.com/start.html

How can I change this to:

> websitename.com/start

I know it have I function for that but I don’t find any documention on google and I don’t know how to description it.

Comment: What searchbar? On the site? Have you looked into URL rewriting? https://aloneonahill.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: if you have Apache as the webserver you can use a `rewrite rule` in either the server config or, more likely, within a `.htaccess` file. Check out [Apache mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Julian:

I think you mean the URL bar with search bar.

Option 1: Rename your file from index.html to index.htm.
This should change the URL link from https://yourpage.com/index.html to https://yourpage.com/.

Option 2: If you link to another HTML document (e.g. page.html) on your website, you can link to the page without the .html extension. Here is an example: Your Link.

Professor Abronsius:

Option 3 (my favorite): Use a rewrite rule in either the server config or within the .htaccess file. (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Thank you to much guys

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the URL bar with `search bar`.


Option 1: Rename your file **from index.html to index.htm**.

This should change the URL link from https://yourpage.com/index.html to https://yourpage.com/.


Option 2: If you link to another HTML document (e.g. page.html) on your website, you can **link to the page without the .html extension**. Here is an example: `<a href="page">Your Link</a>`.